Why does my Brother printer copy/print blank pages?
My Brother Pixma DCP-J100 MFC - J200 printer is running properly and appears to print (makes noises, print head scurrying back and forth), but the result is a blank page or maybe a few blue lines. This happens with test print pages, copies, and pages sent to the printer wirelessly from my laptop.
My four print cartridges have ink and I can visually see the ink inside and shake them and hear the ink. The ink volume on the printer display showed them having enough ink.
I have run the cleaning software and the alignment routine and it spits out blank pages.
I purchased a manual cleaner to get rid of clogs and blockages and all colors passed with, er, flying colors. As I was cleaning, each color ink was distributed on the paper towel under the print head.
Still, I get blank pages.

Since you used the firmware in the Brother printer to make a test page, and it failed, then the issue is the printer itself, and it needs physical maintenance, e.g., special head cleaning or replacement. It is not a software issue.

Get it serviced.

In the future, if you have a question like this, please include the Model # of the printer. Brother makes a lot of different printers, and while "inkjet" could be determined from the context, that still leaves quite a few possible models and some fixes are specific to particular models.

My printer uses four ink cartridges: blue, black, yellow and red.
As I don't have access to any service center here, I tried one last thing to get the printer to actually print. I had already cleaned the print heads using the printer hardware and manually cleaned the print heads with the Printer Cleaning Kit (the liquid that you squirt with a syringe.)
I removed the color cartridges and when I put them back in, the message onscreen asked if the cartridge was "new." I answered "yes" to each of them. The cartridges were not new, but this must have reset something and now the printer is printing fine.
